# Android studio can't find gradle or m2Repository when patching AS or trying to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

AS works fine for my current projects. However, if I try to create a new project, then a new activity, the window "shakes" and comes up with an error "Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo".

If I try to patch AS to the latest version I get issues with it not finding the gradle directory.

However, if I go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio, the gradle/ folder is there and the m2repository is within it.

What is going on here please?

Both these errors can be seen here.

[image]

Thanks,
Riz

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did a clean reinstall of AS based on the  information given here:

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio

This seemed to clear up these issues. Not sure to the details of why this happened though. Seemed to start after a previous install, but one which I guess wasn't as clean...